# Trying to get an ECDH Keypair in android, I run into this error: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: no such algorithm: ECDH for provider BC

Tags: java, android, encryption, diffie-hellman, ecdh

**Main question**: how to get an ECDH key pair in android without having errors.

I want to execute Diffie-Hellman key exchange algorithm. So I wrote:

```
import java.security.KeyPairGenerator;

KeyPairGenerator kpgen =KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("ECDH", "BC");
ECGenParameterSpec genspec = new ECGenParameterSpec("brainpoolp256r1");
kpgen.initialize(genspec);
KeyPair localKeyPair = kpgen.generateKeyPair();
```

And I get this error:

> java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: no such algorithm: ECDH for
> provider BC

So I added SpongyCastle to gradle file and then added this line in onCreate:

```
Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
```

And this to my static method:

```
Security.insertProviderAt(new org.spongycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider(), 1);
```

But I still get error for inconsistency in output types which cannot be fixed by casting to that specific Class.

In total, I want to generate a Key pair, get other side's public key and do key agreement.

Comment: Have you tried to omit the `BC` in `KeyPairGenerator.getInstance()` or to use `SC` instead of `BC`? It is also (probably) not necessary to add the SC provider twice.

Comment: You are right @Topaco. "SC" is the answer. Also this line must exist: Security.insertProviderAt(new org.spongycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider(), 1);